# With the DriveApp FileIterator, how do I work with sets larger than I can process within the limited time you have for processing?

Tags: google-apps-script

The new [`FileIterator`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) in the [`DriveApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) service lets you work through files in a very streamlined way.

```
 // Process all files in the user's Drive.
 var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   myProcessingFunction(file);  
 }
```

In [`DocsList`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/docs-list) which apparently "[is now deprecated](http://youtu.be/0HVJMIeb3aE?t=34m45s)", the [`get*ForPaging`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/docs-list#getAllFilesForPaging%28Integer,Token%29) methods allow retrieval of large sets by providing a Token to paginate with. You can store the token in say a script property and use it to start at the correct place at later invocations.

How do you do this in `DriveApp`? How do you handle the case where you can't iterate over all the files you need to during the limited time you have for processing?

Comment: DocsList is not deprecated. I misspoke. It is however, still "Experimental" as of May 2013.

Comment: Can you use `.search` and somehow filter out the processed ones using search criteria?
https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters

Comment: Thanks for the comment Frederic. Search is pretty rich now so maybe but I was really looking for a 'start from' solution like the token that the get*ForPaging methods provided.

Comment: Thanks Arun. Is there a best practice in DriveApp or is this an enhancement request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the enhancement request to track for this particular request - https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2834

Please add your details/use cases to this and then follow it for further updates.

Comment: This request is fixed. The feature getContinuationToken() is documented here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#getContinuationToken()

Answer (score -1):

I break the effort into two pieces:

```
A) collect files and put them in a Google spreadsheet
B) iterate on each row of the spreadsheet
```

if the script times out part way through, the next time the script triggers it checks to see if there is still work to be done on the spreadsheet.

Comment: How do you put them into a Google Spreadsheet without iterating through them?  Is there a function/command that just dumps it all to a spreadsheet at once?